# Invalid parameter when executing tablediff.exe using Java

Tags: java, sql-server, command-line-arguments

Alrite. So this is what I've got so far. I found a post on how to run an executable through Java. I used that and the tablediff utility is running. But I have to pass arguments to the tablediff utility as required by SQL Server.

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException

    {

        String sourceserver = "-sourceserver source_name";
        String sourcedatabase ="-sourcedatabase dbtest01";
        String sourcetable = "-sourcetable article";
        String destinationserver = "-destinationserver destination_name";
        String destinationdatabase ="-destinationdatabase dbtest02";
        String destinationtable = "-destinationtable article";

        Process process = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\110\\COM\\tablediff.exe",sourceserver,sourcedatabase,sourcetable,destinationserver,destinationdatabase,destinationtable).start();    

        InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line;

        System.out.printf("Output of running %s is:", Arrays.toString(args));

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
        {
          System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
```

I keep getting this error :

```
Output of running [] is:
Microsoft (R) SQL Server Replication Diff Tool 
Copyright (c) 2008 Microsoft Corporation

User-specified agent parameter values:
-sourceserver source_name 
The parameter '-sourceserver source_name' is invalid.
```

The command prompt executes it like this :

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\COM\>tablediff.exe -sourceserver source_name -sourcedatabase dbtest01 -sourcetab
le article -destinationserver destination_name -destinationdatabase dbtest02 -destin
ationtable article

Microsoft (R) SQL Server Replication Diff Tool
Copyright (c) 2008 Microsoft Corporation

User-specified agent parameter values:
-sourceserver source_name
-sourcedatabase dbtest01
-sourcetable article
-destinationserver destination_name
-destinationdatabase dbtest02
-destinationtable article

Table [dbtest01].[dbo].[article] on source_name and Table [dbtest02].[dbo].[art
icle] on destination_name have 1 differences.
Err     id
Dest. Only      N'004       '
The requested operation took 9.1819181 seconds.
```

I don't know why the program is giving the invalid parameter. I tried changing the Strings to just "source_name" and so forth. Doesn't work. I also tried passing the string directly to the Processbuilder.Doesn't work either. It gives me the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

From your input I would say that the source_name and destination_name need to be the names of your database servers

```
String sourceserver = "-sourceserver source_name";
String destinationserver = "-destinationserver destination_name";
```

-sourceserver source_server_name[\instance_name]
Is the name of the source server. **Specify source_server_name for the default instance of SQL Server. Specify source_server_name\instance_name for a named instance of SQL Server.**

-destinationserver destination_server_name[\instance_name]
Is the name of the destination server. Specify destination_server_name for the default instance of SQL Server. **Specify destination_server_name\instance_name for a named instance of SQL Server.** 
EDIT >> 
Can you try -sourceserver \\MSSQLSERVER I think it may be that \ is and escape for the single backslash so you are just getting "\MSSQLSERVER"

Comment: I tried using instance name right now. Changed the sourceserver and destination server to "source_name\\MSSQLSERVER" as MSSQLSERVER is my instance name. Its giving me the same error.

Also the utility seems to work fine in the command prompt using the same arguments. I don't understand what is the problem.

Comment: I did name the source_name and destination_name as the database servers. I just made it generic in nature so that its clear.

Comment: Can you try -sourceserver \\\\MSSQLSERVER  I think it may be that \\ is and escape for the single backslash so you are just getting "\MSSQLSERVER"

Comment: Still getting the same error using \\\\MSSQLSERVER. I also tried using source_name\\\\MSSQLSERVER. I would like to point out that the databases are on the same machine.

Comment: Tried using localhost and 127.0.0.1 and also 127.0.0.1:1433. Doesn't work either.
LOCALHOST and 127.0.0.1 works in cmd prompt.